# jQuery data() not always return all data-attrbutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a strange behavior of jQuery (3.2.1) .data() function.
In **some scenario** it returns empty or not complete objects from `input` element which definitely have some data-attributes.

I have arbitrary code which is working asynchrony. And maybe it can change somehow the `input` element at the same time. However, native function `dataset` always return right result. The .data() not always.

For check that have the next sequence of logging on runtime:

```
var input = $('#input_element');  // jQuery object
console.log(input[0].attributes); // it shows data-attributes presented at the moment
console.log(input.data());       // jQuery .data() returns nothing or half of attributes
console.log(input[0].dataset);   // native function return array of all data-attributes
```

I have tried to use `.removeData()` function without any success.

Before that i created input element and had added attributes from array. And replace the old element with this new one.

```
var input = $('<input id="input_element" />'); // new element
$.each(dataAttr, function (dName, value) {
   input.attr('data-' + dName, value);
});
oldElement.replaceWith(input);
```

I have post the question as an investigation. May be somebody will have the same issue. Or have any idea what can change the behavior of .data() function.

Comment: Can we have more context? Like an example of this in codepen?

Comment: For data inside the element, you have to use val() method

Comment: Can you include HTML at Question? How do you set `data-*` attributes or use jQuery to set `.data()`? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Win - or better: Here using a stack snippet (`<>`) - please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @bigbounty _"For data inside the element, you have to use val() method"_ ? How are `data-*` attributes related to `.val()`?

Comment: _"`// jQuery .data() returns nothing or half of attributes`"_ How can either "nothing" or "half" of `data-*` be returned? We need to be able to run the code that reproduces what you are describing

Comment: OP if you use jQuery `.data()` and then later add a data attribute with `.attr()`, you may not see that added attribute via the `.data()` API. It's hard to say because you did not post enough code.

Comment: I created you a snippet. Please correct it to show YOUR attributes

Comment: @mplungjan Why did you edit OP's Question? Let them provide, or not provide the code. The `data-test2` value is not valid `JSON`

Comment: You mentioned using `.data()` though code uses `.attr()`. Why do you use `.attr()` instead of `.data()` if Question is related to `.data()`? What is `dataAttr`?

Comment: To set the value of a data attribute *when you're using jQuery* you almost always should be using the `.data()` API and not `.attr()`.

Comment: @guest271314 because I wanted to see the actual code in action. I wanted to get him to update with the data as soon as possible - it obviously did not work because we STILL HAVE NO [mcve]

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. 3_

Comment: @mplungjan We now do have a minimal,  complete, and verifiable example. OP appeared to be referencing the replaced element, not the new jQuery object. Suggestion here would be to let OP do the work of composing their own Question, to avoid confusion.

Comment: The example provided does not show the actual data attributes nor is runnable. This site is collaborative

Comment: @Pointy Yes. But I cannot. I need to use attributes, because I use shadow DOM mechanics for live update DOM from server (this is fully switched off during my tests).

Comment: How is `ShadowDOM` related to original Question?

Comment: What is _"some scenario"_?

Comment: @vatavale well jQuery manages data attributes by loading them into its own JavaScript data structure, so you'll have to skip using jQuery `.data()` if that's what you need to do. Personally, I'd find another way of doing things, because I don't like to "fight" with libraries I use.

Answer (score 1):

If you are replacing an element with `.replaceWith()` with a new element having `data-*` attributes you should reference the replacement element `input` if you expect to get the `data-*` attributes that you set at the new jQuery object, not the replaced element `oldElement`

```js
var oldElement = $("input");
console.log(oldElement.data(), oldElement[0].outerHTML);
var input = $("<input />");
var dataAttr = ["a", "b", "c"];
$.each(dataAttr, function (dName, value) {
   input.attr("data-" + dName, value);
});
oldElement.replaceWith(input);
console.log(input.data(), input[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: As you can see in my code I create element by $('<input />') not select old one by $("input") as in your example. And yes at the end I reference this new one element.

Comment: @vatavale What is the issue with code at Answer or code at updated Question? If you do not select `oldElement` then you still have not provided a minimal, complete and verifiable example of what you are describing at original Question

Comment: Thank you. It do not answer my question. Witch is "why in some scenario (which I cannot reproduce in simple example) .data() do not return all data-attributes". Most of the time my code is working. I post the question as an investigation. May be somebody will have the same issue. And I definitely plan to solve it by myself, and post the answer.

Comment: You have not reproduced the issue that you are describing. _"I cannot reproduce in simple example"_ Why not?

Comment: Because I have arbitrary code which is working asynchrony. And maybe it can change somehow the input element at the same time. However, native function _dataset_ always return right result. The .data() not always.

Comment: _"However, native function dataset always return right result"_ Then use `.dataset`. Why did you not include all of the details relating to inquiry at original Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask